# How would I detect the x or y values of a moving object

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I'm trying to make it detectable for when a bullet hits the player. I am trying to make the bulletx[1] variable and the bullety[1] cause the "lose()" function when playerx and playery equal the position of the bullets. I'm not sure where to start, could anyone help me if this is even possible?

```
<script>
let xValues = [];
let yValues = [];
let gunAndBulletx = [];
let gunAndBullety = [];
let gunx = [];
let guny = [];
let bulletx = [];
let bullety = [];
let playerx = 0;
let playery = 0;
let player = document.getElementById("player");
let goalx = 450;
let goaly = 450;
let goal = document.getElementById("goal");
let darken = document.getElementById("darken");
let loseText = document.getElementById("loseText");
let winText = document.getElementById("winText");
let restartButton = document.getElementById("restartButton");
let buttonCenter = document.getElementById("buttonCenter");
let winCount = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  xValues.push(i);
  yValues.push(i);
}
function getGun(a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    gunAndBulletx[i] = xValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * xValues.length)] * 50
    gunAndBullety[i] = yValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * yValues.length)] * 50
    gunx[i] = document.getElementById("gunx" + (i + 1));
    guny[i] = document.getElementById("guny" + (i + 1));
    bulletx[i] = document.getElementById("bulletx" + (i + 1));
    bullety[i] = document.getElementById("bullety" + (i + 1));
  }
}
function gunPosition(a) {
  for (let i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    gunx[i].classList.remove("hide");
    guny[i].classList.remove("hide");
    bulletx[i].classList.remove("hide");
    bullety[i].classList.remove("hide");
    gunx[i].style.left = gunAndBulletx[i] + 5 + "px";
    gunx[i].style.top = 510 + "px";
    guny[i].style.top = gunAndBullety[i] + 5 + "px";
    guny[i].style.left = 510 + "px";
    bulletx[i].style.left = gunAndBulletx[i] + 22.5 + "px";
    bulletx[i].style.top = 510 + "px";
    bullety[i].style.top = gunAndBullety[i] + 22.5 + "px";
    bullety[i].style.left = 510 + "px";
  }
}
function playerStart() {
  player.style.left = 0 + "px";
  player.style.top = 0 + "px";
  playerx = 0
  playery = 0
}
function start() {
  //this is for making the other variables visible or invisible
  player.classList.remove("hide");
  goal.classList.remove("hide");
  darken.classList.add("hide");
  loseText.classList.add("hide");
  winText.classList.add("hide");
  buttonCenter.classList.add("hide");
  restartButton.classList.add("hide");
  //this is for setting the position of the goal
  goal.style.left = goalx + "px";
  goal.style.top = goaly + "px";
}
// this detects when the player wins and what happens
function win() {
  if (playerx === 450) {
    if (playery === 450) {
      player.classList.add("hide");
      player.style.left = 0 + "px";
      player.style.top = 0 + "px";
      playerx = 0
      playery = 0
      goal.classList.add("hide");
      darken.classList.remove("hide");
      winText.classList.remove("hide");
      buttonCenter.classList.remove("hide");
      restartButton.classList.remove("hide");
      winCount = winCount + 1
    }
  }
}
//this detects when a player loses and what happens
function lose() {
  player.classList.add("hide");
  player.style.left = 0 + "px";
  player.style.top = 0 + "px";
  playerx = 0
  playery = 0
  goal.classList.add("hide");
  darken.classList.remove("hide");
  loseText.classList.remove("hide");
  buttonCenter.classList.remove("hide");
  restartButton.classList.remove("hide");
}
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
function checkKey(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.keyCode == '38') {
    //up arrow
    if (playery > 0) {
      playery = playery - 50;
      player.style.position = "absolute";
      player.style.top = playery + "px";
      win()
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode == '40') {
    //down arrow
    if (playery < 450) {
      playery = playery + 50;
      player.style.position = "absolute";
      player.style.top = playery + "px";
      win()
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode == '37') {
    //left arrow
    if (playerx > 0) {
      playerx = playerx - 50;
      player.style.position = "absolute";
      player.style.left = playerx + "px";
      win()
    }
  } else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
    //right arrow
    if (playerx < 450) {
      playerx = playerx + 50;
      player.style.position = "absolute";
      player.style.left = playerx + "px";
      win()
    }
  }
}
}
console.log(winCount);
function play() {
    if (winCount === 5) {
    playerStart();
    start();
    getGun(1);
    gunPosition(1);
    checkKeyVal(1)
    
  }
}
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Start to Finish</title>
  <link href="favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="game-bg">
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx1"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx2"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx3"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx4"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx5"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx6"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx7"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx8"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx9"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="gunx10"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny1"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny2"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny3"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny4"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny5"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny6"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny7"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny8"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny9"></div>
      <div class="gun hide" id="guny10"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety1"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety2"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety3"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety4"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety5"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety6"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety7"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety8"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety9"></div>
      <div class="bullet-side hide" id="bullety10"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx1"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx2"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx3"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx4"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx5"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx6"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx7"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx8"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx9"></div>
      <div class="bullet-up hide" id="bulletx10"></div>
      <div class="player hide" id="player"></div>
      <div class="goal hide" id="goal"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="center">
    <button class="button" onclick="play()">Play</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="darken hide" id="darken">
    <h1 class="alert-text hide" id="loseText">Game Over</h1>
    <h1 class="alert-text hide" id="winText">You Win!</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="center hide" id="buttonCenter">
    <button class="restart-button hide" onclick="play()" id="restartButton">Try again?</button>
  </div>
  
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

<style>
html, body {
  background-color: grey;
}
@keyframes bullet-left {
  0%{left: 510px;}
  50%{left: 0px;}
  51%{left: 510px;}
}
@keyframes bullet-up {
  0%{top: 510px;}
  50%{top: 0px;}
  51%{top: 510px;}
}
.gun{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
.bullet-up{
  width: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: bullet-up;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.bullet-side{
  width: 40px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  animation-name: bullet-left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.center{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.hide{
  display: none;
}
.game-bg{
  width: 500px;
  height: 31.25rem;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.player{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
.goal{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  position: absolute;
}
.darken{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.restart-button{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 999;
  position: absolute;
}
.alert-text{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-size: 144px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 999;
}
</style>
```

As I've said I don't know what to do, and if any extra clarification is needed I will give some.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element you would have to do this while the element is moving and do what you need when condition meets

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem and provide playground  links instead of full code